# How to compute $\int \frac{\text{sgn}(x-t)}{1-t} dt$?

Tags: integration, logarithms

I can tell that I should be getting logarithms because of the $\dfrac1{1-t}$, but the $\text{sgn}(x-t)$ is messing with me, and I don’t know how to proceed.

I tried writing $\text{sgn}(x-t)$ as $\dfrac{\sqrt{(x-t)^2}}{x-t}$, but got the wrong answer. How do you solve $$\int\frac{\text{sgn}(x-t)}{1-t} dt\;?$$

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that the integral is indefinite? Because you need an interval to discuss $\text{sgn}(x-t)$.

Comment: The real integral is definite, Wolfram just didn’t seem to care about boundaries, so I omitted them thinking I was making things easier. The integral goes from a to b, such that x E (a,b). Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$\text{sgn}(x-t)=\begin{cases} 1, \ \text{if} \ x > t \\ 0, \ \text{if} \ x=t \\ -1 \ \text{if} \ x<t\end{cases}$$
Assuming that your interval of integration is $t\in[a,b]$, you have
$$\int_a^b \frac{\text{sgn}(x-t)}{1-t} \text{d}t=\int_a^x \frac{1}{1-t} \text{d}t +\int_x^b \frac{-1}{1-t} \text{d}t$$

Comment: Thank you @Dunkelheit! Your answer was very clear, and now I understand.

Comment: @McMath: You're welcome! I'm glad that this helps. If you want a suggestion, always post the full text of your problem so there will not be any kind of misunderstanding.

Comment: I appreciate your advice, I’ll definitely add more contextual information in future questions 